# When invoking a method with SUPER, how can I have my blessed hash (of the derived class) look like its SUPER class?

Tags: perl, inheritance

When Parent::call_foo() is called, I want it to always call Parent::foo(), regardless if $self is a blessed Parent or a blessed Child, and regardless of the fact that Child is overloading foo().

This code prints:

```
parent foo
parent call_foo, parent foo
child foo
child call_foo, parent call_foo, child foo
```

But I want it to print: **(parent foo on the last line)**

```
parent foo
parent call_foo, parent foo
child foo
child call_foo, parent call_foo, parent foo
```

-

```
use Parent;
use Child;

my $par = Parent->new();
my $chd = Child->new();

$par->foo();
$par->call_foo();

$chd->foo();
$chd->call_foo();
```

-

```
package Parent;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    return bless( {}, $class );
}

sub foo {
    print "parent foo\n";
}

sub call_foo {
    my $self = shift;
    print "parent call_foo, ";
    $self->foo();
}
1;
```

-

```
package Child;
use base qw(Parent);

sub foo {
    print "child foo\n";
}

sub call_foo {
    my $self = shift;
    print "child call_foo, ";
    $self->SUPER::call_foo();
}
1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Parent's `call_foo`, just call `foo` as a subroutine instead of a method.  That will always call the Parent version.

```
package Parent;
...
sub call_foo {
    my $self = shift;
    print "parent call_foo, ";
    foo($self); # always calls Parent::foo
}
```

You could also use `$self->Parent::foo()` instead of `foo($self)`.  The difference is that `$self->Parent::foo()` does a normal method lookup, but starting in the Parent class (i.e. it would work if Parent actually inherited its `foo` method from a base class).  Since you know that `foo` exists in the Parent class, you can save the cost of method lookup by calling it directly.

Comment: Method lookups are only done once -- the result is cached -- so avoiding `$self->Parent::foo()` doesn't actually save anything. That said, I don't like hardcoding the current package name, so I'd probably use `foo($self)`.

Comment: I'm curious, why can't I use `__PACKAGE__::foo()` instead of a hard-code? I can see it doesn't compile, but I can't see why that's not allowed. Either way, I think I'll go with `$self->Parent::foo()`, since some cases in this code it seems the child is overloading a "grandparent" method, but the parent must always call the grandparent version.

Comment: `__PACKAGE__->foo($self);` seems to be the best solution to allow Parent to have inherited foo from a base class, and never call the child version, all without hard coding in the package name.